# limit the type of one argument based on anther argument in typescript function

Tags: typescript

```
interface INavigation {
  children: string[];
  initial: string;
}

function navigation({ children, initial }: INavigation) {
  return null
}
```

I have a function that looks something like the above. I'm trying to see if there is a way to limit the `initial` input to only the list from the `children` array.

For example,

```
// should work
navigation({ children: ["one", "two", "three"], initial: "one" })
navigation({ children: ["one", "two", "three"], initial: "two" })

// should throw a type error
// Type 'four' is not assignable to type 'one' | 'two' | 'three'.
navigation({ children: ["one", "two", "three"], initial: "four" })
```

is there a way to do this using typescript?

I can only think of throwing an error in the function

```
function navigation({ children, initial }: INavigation) {
   
  if (!children.includes(initial)) {
    throw new Error(`${initial} is invalid. Must be one of ${children.join(',')}.`
  }
  return null
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDk4DdgHM5gD2UyA3gLABQyyCAFsADYAmUEIAXMgM5hSi4A2gF0A3FRqhgYYHEZde-ELnGUAvlSowAriAQzCIZCGx4CwQwApStBizYgANMiky5yNVwyn8RKAEoyCWQ2MG0oIxBtRkYqDUoqAHpEnjpCaOZkAHdiAGsqExxfCxBrWyZWdi5BACJDCBrnGrAcxuRmujYG4WdXWXl2+pqPfwKfcysbegqHarqQBqaWwjaOrpqelxBpfq5m1pHNSmTU9JZkME7CLIuATwAHFGgoYiSUgBUHlAByGHSob4ubjGQhgZBwbjcPAmABGjBQRDuj2Q33qgIAPijlhisZ0IBBvgA6MZFCalKZ2SqcZC1IZLVpLPHdXrbNwDGp-cLDNT+IA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `INavigation` type generic so it can capture some specific set of strings.

```
interface INavigation<Children extends readonly string[]> {
  children: Children;
  initial: Children[number];
}
```

Here `Children` is an array of some sort of strings and is assigned as the type of the `children` property. And `initial` is the member type of that array.

And then make your function generic to provide that type:

```
function navigation<Children extends readonly string[]>(
  { children, initial }: INavigation<Children>
) {
  return null
}
```

Then add `as const` to your sample data to ensure these get inferred as string literal types instead of just `string`.

```
// should work
navigation({ children: ["one", "two", "three"], initial: "one" } as const)
navigation({ children: ["one", "two", "three"], initial: "two" } as const)

// should throw a type error
// Type 'four' is not assignable to type 'one' | 'two' | 'three'.
navigation({ children: ["one", "two", "three"], initial: "four" } as const)
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221005#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDk4DdgHM5jAD2IAPAMIAWwANgCZQQjIQAekIdAzso3HSRoBPZFzBRQuANoBdAHzIA3gFgAUMmQJq9RiABcyKrQZMA3Go2hghODQNGdTKSACuAWwBG0GedUBfNTUYFxAEQhJkEGw8AmIyC0NtE2Y2Dm5eCH5BETEJEGkZNTkACkVNJN0AGmQrGxpkPwMMaPxwsgdkuQBKJQTGMBcoZlcaGjUA1TUAeinRSiIXemQAdyIoAGs1KJxWuNLy410DKQAiEggT6pOwVcvka8pGC5lq2uBbAzOQC4bkOB4ECQxF0ti1YiR9lpDkxjl8LlcbkQ7g8nicXjUQNZ3nZ7oiTr9-pogWAQZNVDM5gslmBHkRln9kGAhAAHFDQKBraazAAqLJQAHIYAsoPyajwQEQwH8uFw8FEPDQUGAiIy+ch+edRQAfdWI7W6x4QCD8gB0oJ24JAkIqMOQp3OyLxCMNz1emLqnyFg3xfmlRJAwKAA)

Comment: awesome. This works. Thank you very much! Quick question, is there a way to do this without having to do the `as const` casting?

Comment: @davidhu More black magic: https://tsplay.dev/N7obBN

Comment: @caTS pure magic :)

Comment: i thought i would be able to figure it out from here, but I guess my TS skills still need improvement. How would we handle this same scenario if children is of type `ReactElement<{ name: string, component: () => JSX.Element }>[]`?

Comment: and the goal is to have `initial` only be part of the list of `name` props

Comment: That seems like a new question that deserves an updated example.